# How to convert the norway date format to date format using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the Norwegian date format of the date, but don’t know how to convert it to the standard date format using Python.

I have converted the date format below to standard date format.

```
tir. 18. jun. 2019
```

I have tried using the locale date format, but that is not working.

This the expected output

```
18-07-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/)**

**Ex:**

```
import dateparser 
d = "tir. 18. jun. 2019"
print(dateparser.parse(d).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

**Output:**

```
18-06-2019
```